# Access objects inside a WPF grid

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Application - .Net desktop
Tool - UFT 12.5

UFT is able to identify WPF grid but not any object like checbox, textbox present in cells. How to get reference for such objects to perform any operation on them??

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the type of application you are automating.

Please use the 'Insight' feature in UFT if the operations to perform inside the grid is simple.