# UFT 12.02 cannot identify WpfDataGrid

Tags: hp-uft

### UFT 12.02 cannot identify WpfDataGrid:

OS: Window 7 64 bit

Tool: UFT 12.02

Desktop Application Technology: Dot Net Window based stand alone application(All test objects are identified as WPF)

---

While spying datagrid table in Dot Net based desktop application, UFT recognizes
that object as WpfObject. 
WpfDataGrid table contains two links and one button in each row. UFT is able to 
identify one of the link as "WpfLink" but not the other Link and Button.

Object Spy window Hierarchy shows;

WpfObject:dataGrid2

### Tried few script:

To select a row using below script:
'WpfWindow("xxxx").WpfObject("devname:=dataGrid2").Object.SelectedIndex=1

'It gets the number of rows from datagrig2 and ToString Returns a string that represents the test object.
print WpfWindow("VIDA").WpfObject("devname:=dataGrid2").Object.ToString()

'It gets the number of rows from datagrig2 
print WpfWindow("VIDA").WpfObject("devname:=dataGrid2").Object.Items.Count

But non of this useful as I need to click on the Buttons and Links.

Few post found related to this but not absolute solution.

### Links:

1. [WPF Application Testing with HP UFT (QTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159320/wpf-application-testing-with-hp-uft-qtp)
2. [Access objects inside a WPF grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178671/access-objects-inside-a-wpf-grid)

### Questions:

Can anybody help me out to get the the Button's and Link's properties and select those Buttons and links?

And Unable to find the reason why it is not identifying the WpfDataGrid 
and how to make identify the WpfObject as WpfDataGrid/WpfTable?

The project totally stuck here, as this is one of the major part of the project, 
need the solution as soon as posible.

Please tell, if more information required relating this.

Thanks a Ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct answer:-

1) Open UFT
2) Open your wfp ".exe" file in UFT and run. (YourwpfFile.exe)
3) then you can able to identify the WFP window using object spy.